# Difference between 特色, 特殊, and 特别?

Tags: meaning, difference

What's the difference between 特色, 特殊, and 特别？
Can you please show me some examples?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

特色 is foremost a noun, and can be used to describe a specialty of some sorts, often associated with a region: 龙井茶是杭州西湖的特色。Note that 特殊 is rarely used this way.

But as most Chinese words, it can also take on other functions, such as: 西湖龙井茶的特色泡法。Here, 特殊 can also be used, as a stative verb or an adjective.

中国特色社会主义, or socialism with Chinese characteristics, is another example.

特别 is more of an adverb, as in 我喜欢音乐，特别是摇滚乐 or as in 我特别关注她的看法。